# Trying to make a small games device with Raspberry Pi Zero, help with battery?

Tags: gpio, retropie, battery

I'm trying to make a small retropie emulator with a Raspberry Pi Zero. I would preferable like to make it as small as possible. I am thinking of using this premade HAT for the Pi, as I am not very well versed with Raspberry Pi yet. [Here's the link to the hat](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804196494151.html?src=google&aff_fcid=2207c33d296c490bae3841115611295b-1696598905609-05688-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=2207c33d296c490bae3841115611295b-1696598905609-05688-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=05a91625334345d7a68dad5d1d140a93&afSmartRedirect=y&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa), but that does not come with any battery solution. How would I go about adding a battery and charging system to it? Could I just solder a battery connected to [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1904) directly to the same GPIO pins used for the HAT? Any advice is helpful.